# Making string variables with paste() in R

Tags: r, string, paste

How can I make the below string variables using paste() in R?

```
y1=("aA1","bB2",…,"zZ26")

y2="a.A.1;b.B.2; … ;z.Z.26"
```

Comment: Hi vahid, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add more detail about what you would like to accomplish here?

Comment: This seems like a homework problem. What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Are you aware of the `letters` and `LETTERS` built-in variables?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
y1 <- paste(letters,LETTERS,seq(letters),sep = "")

y2 <- paste(paste(letters,LETTERS,seq(letters),sep = "."),collapse = ";")
```

Comment: I don't think `y1` is an input - I think it's a homework problem to learn about `paste` by creating `y1` and `y2` from scratch.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for reminder! I updated my solution

Answer (score 0):

I used the following commands in R in order to make string variables y1 and y2:

```r
y1 <- c(paste(letters[1:26],LETTERS[1:26],1:26))

y2 <- paste(letters[1:26],".",LETTERS[1:26],".",1:26,collapse = ";")
```

Comment: Use `paste0` instead of  `paste`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using regex and backreference:

```
y2 <- sub("([a-z])([A-Z])(\\d+)", "\\1\\.\\2\\.\\3", y1)
y2
 [1] "a.A.1"  "b.B.2"  "c.C.3"  "d.D.4"  "e.E.5"  "f.F.6"  "g.G.7"  "h.H.8"  "i.I.9"  "j.J.10" "k.K.11" "l.L.12" "m.M.13" "n.N.14"
[15] "o.O.15" "p.P.16" "q.Q.17" "r.R.18" "s.S.19" "t.T.20" "u.U.21" "v.V.22" "w.W.23" "x.X.24" "y.Y.25" "z.Z.26"
```

The backreferences `\\1`, `\\2`, and `\\3` 'recall' the capturing groups `([a-z])`, `([A-Z])`, and `(\\d+)`, respectively, to repeat them in the replacement argument of `sub`; additionally, the escaped metacharacter `\\.`is inserted between each capturing group.

Data:

```
y1 <- paste0(letters, LETTERS, seq(letters))
y1
 [1] "aA1"  "bB2"  "cC3"  "dD4"  "eE5"  "fF6"  "gG7"  "hH8"  "iI9"  "jJ10" "kK11" "lL12" "mM13" "nN14" "oO15" "pP16" "qQ17" "rR18"
[19] "sS19" "tT20" "uU21" "vV22" "wW23" "xX24" "yY25" "zZ26"
```